# Add values in array if it is an Integer

Tags: ruby

```
array=[6, 2, 7, 1, 10, nil, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, nil, 10, nil, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5]
```

If an element is equal to ten I want to grab the next two values in the array and add them to ten, without removing the nil values. The expected output is:

```
[6, 2, 7, 1, 19, nil, 9, 0, 8, 2, 23, nil, 18, nil, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5]
```

Comment: What is desired if there are not two non-nil values after a 10?

Comment: That scenario isn't factored into the equation because I am simply trying to solve a simple code challenge and had trouble finding a solution. This challenge doesn't go beyond what I wrote.

Comment: Regardless of whether the code challenge answered my question, you need to (with an edit), because the question is not now fully specified, which I expect is the reason for the downvote. One might assume each of the last two elements of the array, if a 10, is not to be changed (because two non-nils cannot follow) or, if there is a 10 in the next-to last position and the last value of the array is non-nil, the latter should be added to the 10. One could even have an array `[10,10,nil,....,nil]`. Should either 10 be changed? It doesn't matter what the rule is, but there needs to be one.

Comment: Ah, okay. It was a bowling challenge. I hadn't thought of any edge cases. The array I gave was the array provided by the instructor. Still new-ish to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
def change_da_10s(arr)
  nil_indices = arr.each_index.reject { |i| arr[i] }
  arr.compact.concat([0, 0]).
      each_cons(3).
      map { |v| v.first == 10 ? v.sum : v.first }.
      tap { |aa| nil_indices.each { |i| aa.insert(i, nil) } }
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [6, 2, 7, 1, 10, nil, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, nil, 10, nil, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5]

change_da_10s(arr)
  #=> [6, 2, 7, 1, 19, nil, 9, 0, 8, 2, 23, nil, 18, nil, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5]
```

**Explanation**

The three main steps are as follows.

*Save the indices of the `nil`s.*

```
nil_indices = arr.each_index.reject { |i| arr[i] }
  #=> [5, 11, 13]
```

*Remove the `nil`s, add two zeroes at the end, then map each triple to the correct value.*

```
a = arr.compact.
        concat([0, 0]).
        each_cons(3).
        map { |v| v.first == 10 ? v.sum : v.first }
  #=> [6, 2, 7, 1, 19,      9, 0, 8, 2, 23,      18,      3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5]
```

The gaps in the return values are merely to show where the `nil`s were.

This calculation requires the following steps.

```
arr = [6, 2, 7, 1, 10, nil, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, nil, 10, nil, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5]

b = arr.compact
  #=> [6, 2, 7, 1, 10,      9, 0, 8, 2, 10,      10,      3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5] 
c = b.concat([0, 0])
  #=> [6, 2, 7, 1, 10,      9, 0, 8, 2, 10,      10,      3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5, 0, 0] 
e = c.each_cons(3)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [6, 2, 7, 1, 10, 9, 0, 8, 2, 10, 10, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5, 0, 0]
  # :each_cons(3)>
```

We can see the values that will generated by this enumerator by invoking  [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries) (or [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a)) on it.

```
e.entries
  #=> [[6, 2, 7], [2, 7,  1], [7,  1, 10], [ 1, 10, 9], [10, 9, 0], [9, 0, 8],
  #    [0, 8, 2], [8, 2, 10], [2, 10, 10], [10, 10, 3], [10, 3, 5], [3, 5, 7],
  #    [5, 7, 2], [7, 2,  5], [2,  5,  5], [ 5,  5, 0], [5, 0, 0]]
```

Lastly,

```
e.map { |v| v.first == 10 ? v.sum : v.first }
  #=> [6, 2, 7, 1, 19, 9, 0, 8, 2, 23, 18, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5]
```

[Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) made its debut in Ruby v2.4. For earlier versions use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

*Shove the `nil`s back into `a` where they belong.*

```
a.tap { |aa| nil_indices.each { |i| aa.insert(i, nil) } }
  #=> [6, 2, 7, 1, 19, nil, 9, 0, 8, 2, 23, nil, 18, nil, 3, 5, 7, 2, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Why'd you add two zeroes to the end?

Comment: If there is a 10 in the last position, presumably it will remain 10. By adding two zeroes I don't have to treat that as a special case. I simply compute `10+0+0`. Similarly, if the array ends `[10, 3]`, I can use `[10, 3, 0, 0]` to compute `10+3+0`. If the array ends `[10, nil]`, I can use `[10, 0, 0]` (after `nil`s have been removed) to compute `10+0+0`. Note that the number of triples equals the size of the array after the `nil`s have been removed, which is why `map` applies.

Comment: Neat, very helpful.